# Iphone8 Images/Video To CentOS7 Server Bypassing Icloud Storage?

Tags: security, backup, storage, apple, iphone

Is it possible when I take a picture/video with my Iphone8 that the images/videos get automatically synced to my CentOS7 server some how to a specific directory? I see the Snap Store has Icloud for Linux so I installed it but none of the applications worked with CentOS7 so I uninstalled it.

I am constantly having to look between my server and my phone for various pieces of content.  I am wasting time on trivial matters that should be automated.  I realize I am using a consumer based mobile device and the ideal answer is "get an android phone".  Flow with me Gentlemen.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud is the solution.  Only drawback is with photo I have to upload them manually because I am not on an android.  I was hoping to take a photo and save directly to Nextcloud.